# Wordpress custom posts on magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I'm trying to display some Wordpress custom posts on Magento, with Fishpig extension (full integration).

There's no documentation on the extension web site. I cannot seem to be able to figure how to do this.

Any help?

[EDIT]

Ok, what i'm looking for is :

I've created custom posts on my wordpress backend named 'Slides'. I would like to use them on magento homepage, to create a slider.
On one hand, when i look on fishpig template, i see a unique $post->getPost(), where i would like, for example, had details of which type of post i would like to use. I know it can not be done that way, surely i should a predefined fishpig method (that i can't find), or create a new one.
On the other hand, in fishpig layout this time, there's possible action like :

`<action method="setTitle"><title>Latest Posts</title></action>`

I tought i can configure in this way the post type i wanted to display..

Sorry, but i've not online URL to show you the project, i'm still in the earlier part of the project..

Thx

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you have a URL we can look at? Can you please elaborate about what you're attempting to do, what you have tried, etc... ?

Comment: Snoop around the various blocks included with Fishpig. They provide all the methods you'll need to get posts, post lists, etc.

Comment: @pspahn : Questions edited (sorry for the misunderstood of the process) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for here is:

```
<action method="setPostType"><type>yourposttypeslug</type></action>
```

This should follow the snippet you already had within the recent posts block as below:

```
<block type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts" name="wordpress.widget.recent_posts" as="recent_posts" template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/posts.phtml">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Latest Posts</title></action>
    <action method="setPostType"><type>yourposttypeslug</type></action>
    <action method="setPostCount"><post_count>3</post_count></action>
</block>
```